# How to get Android MediaPlayer() to stop when app is closed?

Tags: android

My android app creates a MediaPlayer() and plays a looping song.  I need to have it stop playing when the user leaves the app.  I also need to get at the volume buttons somehow, to let users adjust the songs volume...  Any Ideas?

```
MediaPlayer mp;

public void setupMediaPlayer()
{
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.song);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start(); 
}

public void stopMediaPlayer()
{
    mp.stop();
}
```

Comment: Dear god please don't do this unless your app is specifically a music player app

Comment: Is there another way of equal ease - I think at this juncture my app can handle all the overhead of this mediaplayer.  Also song is very small less than 500k.

Comment: I think his point was that an app playing a looping song is most likely going to be really annoying, not that it wasn't technically possible.

Comment: Video Games. Those usually have music. Otherwise they appear to be crude. What if you play Super Mario Bros. and the music stops playing after it's first run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the first half of your question: you should get what you want if you call `stopMediaPlayer()` inside `onPause()` and `onDestroy()`. Example:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopMediaPlayer();
}
```

Per the second half: Try taking a look at the [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) class (particularly [AUDIO_FOCUS_GAIN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)), and see if that can handle what you're looking for.

Make sure the looping audio makes sense in the context of the app, though...if there's one thing I don't miss from the amateur websites of the mid-90's it's that awful MIDI background music that everyone seemed to put in them...

Comment: naw this is a *smooth* beat but I fear users would become addicted to the sound.

Answer (score 1):

Also think about onResume(), to continue your looping song when the user comes back to your app.

Answer (score 1):

stopMediaPlayer didn't work for me as per eldarerathis' answer but this did:

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
}
```

Dunno why though...

Edited:

According to the course I'm doing though [this](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud839/lessons/7863766808/concepts/80820923030923/%22this%22) is the correct way to do it.

Maybe one day I'll figure out the difference. :)